# how to convert Reduce output to Julia symbolic expression?

Tags: julia

In Julia, I use Reduce package to do integration since Julia Symbolics.jl does not have integrate command in it.

But I am not able to figure how to convert the output (the anti derivative) to Julia symbolic expression so I can use it inside Julia symbolic, and not using the Reduce package.

This is what I tried

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.1 (2021-12-22)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Symbolics    
julia> using Reduce    
julia> @variables x
1-element Vector{Num}:
 x

#use Reduce to do the integration
julia> output = :(int(sin(x),x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))

 julia> typeof(output)
 Expr
```

Now, I want to use the output `-cos(x)` as symbolic expression using Julia Symbolics. How to convert it?

Now it gives an error as is

```
julia> Symbolics.simplify(output^2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ^(::Expr, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  ^(::Union{AbstractChar, AbstractString}, ::Integer) at G:\nabbasi\data\CDROM\JULIA_language\julia-1.7.1-win64\julia-1.7.1\share\julia\base\strings\basic.jl:721
  ^(::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal, ::Integer) at G:\nabbasi\data\CDROM\JULIA_language\julia-1.7.1-win64\julia-1.7.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\LinearAlgebra\src\diagonal.jl:196
  ^(::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal, ::Real) at G:\nabbasi\data\CDROM\JULIA_language\julia-1.7.1-win64\julia-1.7.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\LinearAlgebra\src\diagonal.jl:195
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] literal_pow(f::typeof(^), x::Expr, #unused#::Val{2})
   @ Base .\intfuncs.jl:325
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[9]:1
```

This is the same output, but now it is Julia Symbolics expression:

```
julia> f=-cos(x)
-cos(x)

julia> typeof(f)
Num

julia> Symbolics.simplify( f^2)
cos(x)^2
```

How does one convert output of Reduce expression to Julia Symbolics expression, may be for further processing?

It is possible to convert the Reduce output to string

```
julia> g=string(output)
"-(cos(x))"
```

But do not know how to convert the above string now to Symbolics expression. `parse` does not work. May be there is different command?

References

Reduce Julia package https://docs.juliahub.com/Reduce/wEGBP/1.2.5/

Julia Symbolics package https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like these two packages (Reduce and Symbolics) are using rather different formats for their symbolic expressions. Reduce is using Julia's native [`Expr`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.Expr) type, the same type used to represent Julia code itself, while Symbolics is using an approach where calling a function on one or more special variable designated with `@variables` will return an object that records the operations performed on those variables:

```
julia> using Reduce, Symbolics

julia> a = :(-(cos(x)))
:(-(cos(x)))

julia> @variables x;

julia> b = -(cos(x))
-cos(x)

julia> typeof(a)
Expr

julia> typeof(b)
Num
```

To see and compare what is actually inside these two different objects `a` and `b`, we can use Julia's very useful `dump` function:

```
julia> dump(a)
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Symbol -
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((2,))
        1: Symbol cos
        2: Symbol x

julia> dump(b)
Num
  val: SymbolicUtils.Mul{Real, Int64, Dict{Any, Number}, Nothing}
    coeff: Int64 -1
    dict: Dict{Any, Number}
      slots: Array{UInt8}((16,)) UInt8[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
      keys: Array{Any}((16,))
        1: #undef
        2: #undef
        3: #undef
        4: #undef
        5: #undef
        ...
        12: #undef
        13: SymbolicUtils.Term{Real, Nothing}
          f: cos (function of type typeof(cos))
          arguments: Array{SymbolicUtils.Sym{Real, Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}}}((1,))
            1: SymbolicUtils.Sym{Real, Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}}
              name: Symbol x
              metadata: Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}
                parent: Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}
                key: Symbolics.VariableSource <: Any
                value: Tuple{Symbol, Symbol}
          metadata: Nothing nothing
          hash: Base.RefValue{UInt64}
            x: UInt64 0xd47301bdec8cde1c
        14: #undef
        15: #undef
        16: #undef
      vals: Array{Number}((16,)) Number[#undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, 1, #undef, #undef, #undef]
      ndel: Int64 0
      count: Int64 1
      age: UInt64 0x0000000000000001
      idxfloor: Int64 13
      maxprobe: Int64 0
    sorted_args_cache: Base.RefValue{Any}
      x: Array{Any}((2,))
        1: Int64 -1
        2: SymbolicUtils.Term{Real, Nothing}
          f: cos (function of type typeof(cos))
          arguments: Array{SymbolicUtils.Sym{Real, Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}}}((1,))
            1: SymbolicUtils.Sym{Real, Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}}
              name: Symbol x
              metadata: Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}
                parent: Base.ImmutableDict{DataType, Any}
                key: Symbolics.VariableSource <: Any
                value: Tuple{Symbol, Symbol}
          metadata: Nothing nothing
          hash: Base.RefValue{UInt64}
            x: UInt64 0xd47301bdec8cde1c
    hash: Base.RefValue{UInt64}
      x: UInt64 0x0000000000000000
    metadata: Nothing nothing
```

and they are indeed quite different.

That's not to say that you can't use the two packages together though. Since an `Expr` is the type used to represent Julia code as data, all you need to do is *evaluate* that `Expr` to obtain the same result as if you had called the functions therein (going the other way would be another matter, though!). So we can write:

```
julia> output = :(int(sin(x),x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))

julia> output = eval(output)
-cos(x)

julia> Symbolics.simplify(output^2)
cos(x)^2
```

Alternatively, you could add the `^2` to `output` while keeping it in `Expr` form by using one of Julia's many ways of manipulating `Expr`s, and only later `eval` it when you need to pass it to `Symbolics`:

```
julia> output = :(int(sin(x),x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))

julia> output_squared = :($output^2) # interpolate one Expr into another
:((-(cos(x))) ^ 2)

julia> Symbolics.simplify(eval(output_squared))
cos(x)^2
```

There may more performant approaches of which I am unaware, since I have not extensively used either package, and using `eval` is arguably a bit of a hack. But, this should work without error for any case where the functions in your Reduce expression are defined Julia functions that Symbolics knows about (and as long as you're evaluating them in the right scope).

Comment: Thanks. After more testing, there are cases where `eval` gives an error and I am not able to figure a way around it. Here is an example `output = :(int( exp(x),x)) |> rcall` and now `eval(output)` gives error.  I made sure all packages are loaded and that I did `@variables x` before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, it looks like that returns `:(ℯ ^ x)` instead of `:(exp(x))`, and Symbolics doesn't know how to handle `ℯ ^ x`

Comment: You can fix that in one line though: `import Base.^; ^(::Irrational{:ℯ}, x::Num) = exp(x)`

Comment: It would probably be an easy PR to Symbolics to add the method `^(::Irrational{:ℯ}, x::Num) = exp(x)` so you don't have to do that manually

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of using Julia to access Reduce to test integrals  I have. The problem is that the integration variable can be different each time and functions returned from Reduce, Symbolics.jl might not know about. Here there was `e` which should be `exp()`. I am sure there will be others.  At first I thought Reduce package and Symbolics will have common notation. My goal was to test Reduce integration capability. I thought using Julia will be easier than using Reduce directly. I will instead try to use Reduce itself directly on Linux and bypass all these issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/pull/506

Comment: They definitely do have different notation, but I do also suspect Symbolics would want to have methods for at least normal Julia syntax like this, so don't hesitate to post if you run into other such cases