# How to use Symbolics expression in a call to the integrate command in Reduce package

Tags: julia

Since `Symbolics.jl` does not have integrate command, I am using `Reduce.jl` to do the integration.

Reduce works ok when passing the integrand as literal expression in the command itself as follows

```
:(int(sin(x),x)) |> rcall
```

But when putting the integrand in a variable first, and then using this variable inside the call, it does not work.  I tried using `eval()` but Julia hanged.

Here is a complete MWE

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.1 (2021-12-22)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Reduce

julia> :(int( sin(x),x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))
```

Works fine. But I wanted to make the integrand a variable.

```
julia>  using Symbolics
julia> @variables x
julia> integrand = sin(x)
julia> :(int( integrand ,x)) |> rcall

         :(integrand * x)
```

Which means it did not see the variable `integrand` from outside. So I tried adding eval around it

```
julia> :(int( eval(integrand) ,x)) |> rcall
```

But now Julia hanged.

These two packages have to work together better otherwise If I can't use variables from outside Reduce package in the commands inside Reduce, this will make it very limited to use. For example, I wanted to build some symbolic expressions using Symbolics and then use them in integrate command in Reduce package.

Is there a way around this?

I do know that the `x`  used by Symbolics and the `x` used by Reduce are different. For example, from fresh Julia session, I can type first thing

```
:(int(sin(x),x)) |> rcall
```

And it works, without having to use `@variables x` first. It looks like Reduce uses it own symbolic symbols without the need to declare them first.

But to build a symbolic expression with `x` outside Reduce, one needs to first use `@variables x`.   This could be the cause the problem. I do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for starters when you write

```
:(int(integrand, x))
```

this is called a [*quote*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Quoting), which produces a Julia object called an `Expr`. It's nothing to do with either Symbolics or Reduce, but rather a built-in part of the language (which Reduce just happens to use to represent symbolic expressions).

Whenever you write anything between the parens of `:(...)`, it's much like writing as string between the `"`s of `"..."` which is just a quote of the code you wrote inside the `:()`.

This is important because it means that neither the `Expr` your have just constructed, nor any program you may pass this `Expr` to have any way of knowing that, in this particular case, what you really wanted to do was to [*interpolate*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-expression-interpolation) the value of a variable called *integrand* into this `Expr`.

You can always interpolate one `Expr` into another with `$` (just like [interpolating a variable into a string](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation)), so if you had written

```
julia> using Reduce

julia> integrand = :(sin(x))
:(sin(x))

julia> :(int( $integrand, x))
:(int(sin(x), x))

julia> :(int( $integrand, x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))
```

This would have worked as desired. (And as an aside, yes, `@variables` is purely a Symbolics.jl thing; it has no meaning to Reduce or to `Expr`s more broadly.)

However, it looks like you want to be able to interpolate a Symbolics.jl expression into an `Expr`, not just another `Expr` into an `Expr`. To my pleasant surprise however, this appears to *just work* with the same interpolation syntax:

```
julia> using Symbolics

julia> @variables x;

julia> integrand = sin(x)
sin(x)

julia> :(int( $integrand, x))
:(int(sin(x), x))

julia> using Reduce

julia> :(int( $integrand, x)) |> rcall
:(-(cos(x)))
```

Finally, I think it is worth noting that, as far as I know, neither of these packages Symbolics and Reduce were designed to work with each other at all. The fact that you can make it happen is basically a quirk of the fact that Reduce chose to use Julia's built-in `Expr` type as its symbolic expression type.

In this context, if you think about it for a minute, hopefully it will be clear why `eval` cannot help you here; if anything that's the exact opposite of what you want in this case; it can take an `Expr` and evaluate it, which, happens to let you [turn an `Expr` into a symbolics expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706263/how-to-convert-reduce-output-to-julia-symbolic-expression) (because evaluating functions is, coincidentally, how you create symbolics expressions) -- but very much not the reverse.